# No se encuentra una clase que si esta instanciada. Ubuntu budgie 22.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, http, error500

Me sale este error que les adjunto. Estoy usando use y namespace, no se si sea la causa, también estoy trabajando con el patrón de diseño MVC con Bramus Router. Instale el Bramus router desde composer. Y mi version de php es PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.10.

Página de inicio: Este es el documento que no se me muestra en el navegador.

```
<?php
namespace Luis\Os\views;

use Luis\Os\views\layouts\Head;
use Luis\Os\views\layouts\Foot;

$head = new Head;
echo $head->index();

//contenido

$foot = new Foot;
echo $foot->index();
```

Archivo de rutas:

```
<?php
namespace Luis\Os\lib;

$router = new \Bramus\Router\Router();

$router->match('GET', '/', function() {
    require_once ("src/views/inicio.php");
});

$router->match('GET', '/index.php', function() {
    require_once ("src/views/inicio.php");
});

$router->run();
```

Página index: La idea es que sea un SPA.

```
<?php 
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require 'src/lib/routes.php';
```

Por si a caso les paso el código en apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . public/index.php [L]
```

La estructura de carpetas:

```
public
|__src
   | |_lib
   |    |__routes.php
   |__views
        | |__layouts
        |     |__head.php
        |     |__foot.php
        |____inicio.php
```

Archivo Error.log:
me aparece esto:

> [php:error] [pid 7798] [client ::1:42000] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> Error: Class "Luis\Os\views\layouts\Head" not found in
> /var/www/app_luis/public/src/views/inicio.php:7\nStack trace:\n#0
> /var/www/app_luis/public/src/lib/routes.php(7): require_once()\n#1
> [internal function]: Luis\Os\lib\{closure}()\n#2
> /var/www/app_luis/public/vendor/bramus/router/src/Bramus/Router/Router.php(458):
> call_user_func_array()\n#3
> /var/www/app_luis/public/vendor/bramus/router/src/Bramus/Router/Router.php(440):
> Bramus\Router\Router->invoke()\n#4
> /var/www/app_luis/public/vendor/bramus/router/src/Bramus/Router/Router.php(287):
> Bramus\Router\Router->handle()\n#5
> /var/www/app_luis/public/src/lib/routes.php(14):
> Bramus\Router\Router->run()\n#6
> /var/www/app_luis/public/index.php(3): require('...')\n#7 {main}\n
> thrown in /var/www/app_luis/public/src/views/inicio.php on line 7,
> referer: http://localhost/

Comment: Deberías revisar el fichero error.log generado porque un error 500 suele ser bien descrito ahí.

Comment: ¿Puede ser que Ubuntu no acepte los namespace o que no acepte en la ruta las diagonales invertidas "\" ?

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví, cambié el código del archivo inicio.php; cambié las mayusculas de Head y Foot por minusculas head y foot respectivamente, ya que estos archivos en la carpeta "layouts" estaban escritos así:
Inicio.php (antes):

```
use Luis\Os\views\layouts\Head;
use Luis\Os\views\layouts\Foot;
```

Inicio.php (despues):

```
use Luis\Os\views\layouts\head;
use Luis\Os\views\layouts\foot;
```

Comment: en linux, todos los archivos y rutas son case sensitive ;)